# GenericForeignKey on another db model

Tags: database, django, django-models, orm

On my Widget model, I would like to have a GenericForeignKey to a model named Filter, which is mapped on another database table with an appropriate db router:

```
# default database
class Widget(models.model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, blank=True, null=True)
    object_id = IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()

# router on the second db
class Db2_Manager(models.manager.Manager):
    db = 'db2'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return queryset(self.model, using=self.db)

# Model on the second db
class Filter(models.Model):
    title=models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'abc\".\"_filter'

    objects = Db2_Manager()
```

Example in a django shell:

```
[in] : f1 = Filter.objects.first() # This is the external db object, which works
[in] : f1.title
[out]: 'My title'
[in]:  new_widget = Widget(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(f1), object_id=f1.id)
[in] : new_widget.save()
[in] : new_widget.content_type
[out]: <ContentType: filter>
[in] : new_widget.object_id
[out]: 23
[in] : new_widget.content_object
[out]: ProgrammingError: schema "abc" does not exist
```

I have replicated the django_content_type table on the Filter database (db2), but I get the error above...any suggestions on how to correctly route `new_widget.content_object` to the correct db?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#limitations-of-multiple-databases

Django doesn't support ForeignKey or ManyToMany relationships that span across different dbs. The same will apply to GenericForeignKey.

Your two models need to be in the same db.

Comment: I know that limitation, but there is no trick or workaround to have that content_object filled? Unfortunately I cannot move any model...

Comment: I don't think you want to duplicate the content type table... it is Django GenericForeignKey mechanism itself which needs patching